# Can a Bash 2 sourced script tell what directory it's stored in?

Tags: bash

**${BASH_SOURCE[0]}** is not implemented yet with BASH_VERSINFO < 3

I was wondering because no solution seems to fit my needs for companies still wanting to keep servers with way old bashs

thanks

Comment: Probably time to upgrade to a new (4.3?) version of Bash.  You can compile it on or for the older machines easily enough — assuming you can do any compiling for those machines.  If you can't, you should probably give up on `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`, or write a function of some sort to simulate it, assuming you aren't dealing with devious scripting that could mislead such a function (you probably aren't).

Comment: Maybe it already existed: `echo ${BASH_ARGV[0]}`